# How does TfBertForSequenceClassification work?

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, text-classification, multiclass-classification

The main job of bert is two - one is to predict the masked word and second is to predict the if sentence b is related to sentence a or not , then how TfBertForSequenceClassification  is helping me for multiclass classification task?

Suppose my training data consists of 200 sentences and 5 labels ( Q, U, E, R, Y) How this model is able to successfully classify which sentence will be in Q or which sentence will fall in E?

Can one explain this with an example? TIA

Answer (score 1):

The two tasks you mention (prediction of masked words, next sentence prediction) were used to pre-train the BERT model for these two tasks and nothing else - in it's base form, BERT is not capable of sequence classification or other tasks. However, as a byproduct of this pre-training the BERT is capable of so called latent representations of words and sentences in context.

How does it work? BERT is a large model with many layers. Roughly speaking, the idea is to take the model that was trained for the two mentioned tasks, forget the last layer, and use that as an input for custom layer. This way we can use the BERT model for many different tasks.

When you initialize the BERT for sequence classification like this:

```
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', num_labels=2)
```

it actually initializes a classifaction layer with random weights on top of pre-trained BERT. This initialization even outputs this warning in the logs:

```
Some layers of TFBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['classifier', 'dropout_19', 'pre_classifier']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

### Why does it work?

Note that the two tasks the BERT was pre-trained on can be trained on a dataset that was created in an unsupervised manner: for masked worked prediction, take any text and randomly drop 15% words; for next sentence prediction (which is basically a binary prediction whether sentence B can directly follow sentence A), take one sentence and pair with next or a random sequence. Thanks to this, BERT can be pre-trained on a gigantic dataset that would not be possible to create using human supervision.

*(Similarly, for example GPT models were pre-trained with the objective to predict next word, which is why they are generally more suited for text generation. BERT model uses bidirectional approach which may make it more suitable for tasks such as sequence classification.)*

Thanks to massivenes of the dataset the BERT was pre-trained on, it basically learned latent representation of language. For example, BERT embeddings of similar words are similar vectors. Also, BERT is capable of contextual embeddings, which means that the same word is embedded differently depending on its context. This is very useful and means that BERT can be finetuned on esentially any natural language processing task, including sequence classification.